# Match element's attribute to array name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm working on a page that has multiple lists:

```
<ul class="policies" id="p-1">
  <li><a href="p_1_1">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="p_1_2">Foo2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="policies" id="p-2">
  <li><a href="p_2_1">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="p_2_2">Foo2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each one of these `href`s has an array with a matching name:

```
var p_1_1 = ['ab', 'az', 'tx', 'wz'];
var p_1_2 = ['av', 'bq', 'cf', 'ts'];
```

Whenever the user clicks on one of the list items, I'm using JavaScript/jQuery to append a dynamic number of images to an empty div. The sources of the images will be taken from the array items:

```
$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var useArray = $(this).attr('href').toString();
} );

for ( var i=0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
  $('div').append('<img src="'+ array[i] +'" />');
}
```

My question is, how can I match the `href` attribute to the proper array name in order to output the right set of items? For example, when a user clicks on `<a href="p_1_1">`, I need to output the items from array `p_1_1`. My experience with arrays in JavaScript is very limited, and appreciate any help on the subject.

Comment: `window[useArray]` if it's in the global scope, but you'd be better of with an object and using keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of separate arrays, wrap them all up in an object using your strings as keys:

```
var myStuff = {
    p_1_1 : ['ab', 'az', 'tx', 'wz'],
    p_1_2 : ['av', 'bq', 'cf', 'ts']
};
```

Now you can retrieve them easily with:

```
var foo = myStuff["p_1_1"];
```

Or in your code:

```
var useArray = $(this).attr('href').toString();
var array = myStuff[useArray];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried using `window[useArray]`, which only returned `undefined`, but didn't have the proper understanding of objects and keys.